# how to query lookup field id in standard Account using Button and Links

Tags: button

[image]

Hi,I need to pass lookup field id to the vf page.i Used __r.Id,but not accepting.Need your suggestion,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Custom Buttons and Links, you need to add the Id to the field name:

```
{!Contact.Active_Member_ReferralId__c}
```

This is the only place where this behavior exists, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Too fast (y) as usual

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox  i need lookup field id.if i use like this {!Contact.Active_Member_Referral__c} iam not getting id.it is displaying simple text.

Comment: @developersfdc That's odd. It's been a while since I've used custom links, but I tested it, and sure enough, there is something special you need to do. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: @CloudNinja Yeah, one of those sleepless nights.